# Inheritance methods built-in type

Tags: python

```
class Mylist(list):pass
y = Mylist('abc')
y
['a', 'b', 'c']
y.__dict__
{}
```

Mylist class inherits from the built-in type list. Why when outputting instance y displays the list(Object y is empty)?

Answer (score 1):

List object have no `__dict__`:

```
>>> l = []
>>> l.__dict__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

The list data are stored in some field of the C structure storing the object. When you inherits from `list`, you get the `__dict__` attribute but the list data are still stored in the C attribute. That's why you don't see them. Here is the C source of the list type (Python 2.7.2):

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    /* Vector of pointers to list elements.  list[0] is ob_item[0], etc. */
    PyObject **ob_item;

    /* ob_item contains space for 'allocated' elements.  The number
     * currently in use is ob_size.
     * Invariants:
     *     0 <= ob_size <= allocated
     *     len(list) == ob_size
     *     ob_item == NULL implies ob_size == allocated == 0
     * list.sort() temporarily sets allocated to -1 to detect mutations.
     *
     * Items must normally not be NULL, except during construction when
     * the list is not yet visible outside the function that builds it.
     */
    Py_ssize_t allocated;
} PyListObject;
```

The objects are stored in the `ob_item` array whose allocated size is in `allocated`.

Answer (score 0):

`y` inherits the `list` constructor, which takes the elements of `'abc'` and makes them the elements of `y`. The fact that the dict is empty means little; the list's elements are not stored in its dict.

Comment: @user2494676: I can't tell what you're trying to say.